# SQL: Sum of group and Sub group

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, case

I Have the data in the following format:

```
Date    id  impressions
1-Jan   1   10
1-Jan   2   20
1-Jan   3   30
1-Jan   1   15
1-Jan   2   25
1-Jan   3   35
2-Jan   1   50
2-Jan   2   60
2-Jan   3   70
2-Jan   1   55
2-Jan   2   65
2-Jan   3   75
```

I want the result as:

```
Date    All_impressions     Id2_Impressions
1-Jan     135                 45
2-Jan     375                 135
```

I tried doing:

```
SELECT DATE, 
    SUM(Impressions) AS All_impressions
    , CASE WHEN id=2 SUM(impressions) ELSE 0
        END as Id2_Impressions
GROUP BY DATE,id
```

This did not display how I wanted it to.
What can I do different?

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  The correct syntax for the conditional aggregation is:

```
SELECT DATE, 
       SUM(Impressions) AS All_impressions,
       SUM(CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN impressions ELSE 0 END) as Id2_Impressions
FROM ??
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE;
```

That is, the `CASE` expression is an argument to the `SUM()` function.  You also need a `FROM` clause; I assume that was just an oversight.

I should note that more recent versions of Postgres support the `FILTER` clause.  This can be a wee bit more efficient than the `SUM(CASE)`, but that is not the path you have started down.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for the reply. I realized how I have misrepresented the data. Please take a look at the source data now.

Comment: @Cerberus . . . The query in this answer would appear to do what you want.